# Removing duplicate values in a two dimensional array java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I'm having a very big problem, and it is because I need to remove any duplicate number in a random X x Y array. I tried to do it by writing four "fors" one inside the other, but it didn't work. Can someone help me?
Let's say that there's 34 three times in the array, so the first one will remain 34 and the others will be set to 0, and the other 0's will remain 0.

```
for (int linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColunas; coluna++) {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
    }

    for (int linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColunas; coluna++) {
            int numeroAtual = matriz[linha][coluna];
            for (int linha2 = 0; linha2 < tamanhoLinhas; linha2++) {
                for (int coluna2 = 0; coluna2 < tamanhoColunas; coluna2++) {
                    if (numeroAtual == matriz[linha][coluna]){
                        matriz[linha][coluna] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoLinhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamanhoColunas; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Always, always, show your code.

Comment: All right, but it's just because I don't have XD but I can try.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? What is it doing that you don't expect?

Comment: All right, it's something like that, and what's that actually doing is that the array is being printed with all it's values = 0

Comment: Are you trying to produce an array where all the values are distinct and no two values are equal?

Comment: Well, it's something like that, actually what I want to do is to create an array with random values, and then the program should process the array and switch every duplicate value it may have for 0

Comment: That's not clear enough. If you find a duplicate, say the value `34`, do you want both instances cleared or just one? If just one, which one (the top-leftmost or bottom-rightmost)?  What about cells that happen to get set to zero initially?  Maybe you should use a different value, like -1, to mark duplicates instead?

Comment: Well, let's say that there's `34` as you say, 3 times in the array, so the first one will remain `34` and the others will be set to 0.

Comment: And the ones that are already 0 will remain zero, because the program shall print the original array as well, so the user may check if the 0's are duplicates or not

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinhas; linha++) {
    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColunas; coluna++) {
        int numeroAtual = matriz[linha][coluna];
        for (int linha2 = 0; linha2 < tamanhoLinhas; linha2++) {
            for (int coluna2 = 0; coluna2 < tamanhoColunas; coluna2++) {
                if (numeroAtual == matriz[linha][coluna]){
                    matriz[linha][coluna] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code results in setting every element of the array to zero.  As an example, let's say

```
linha == 3, coluna == 3
```

upon entering the third `for` loop, and `numeroAtual == 22`.  The inner loops will scan the entire array and at some point will get to [3,3], which will be equal to `numeroAtual`; this will cause the value of `matriz[3,3]` to be set to zero.

That will repeat for every element in the matrix.

Comment: Exactly, I tested it now and it gave me the same result you said man.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it, but it's a little different now. 
Initially, the program would modify all of the repeated numbers, but now the user chooses only one, and the program creates a random two dimensional array and find the repeated numbers and switch them for 0.
Here is how I did it:
    public void questao7(int numeroSelecionado) {

```
    int tamanhoLinhas = (rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
    int tamanhoColunas = (rand.nextInt(9) + 1);
    int matriz[][] = new int[tamanhoLinhas][tamanhoColunas];
    boolean duplicado = false;

    for (int linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColunas; coluna++) {
            matriz[linha][coluna] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Matriz original: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoLinhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamanhoColunas; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int linha = 0; linha < tamanhoLinhas; linha++) {
        for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tamanhoColunas; coluna++) {
            if (!duplicado) {
                if (matriz[linha][coluna] == numeroSelecionado){ 
                    duplicado = true;
                }                     
            } else if (matriz[linha][coluna] == numeroSelecionado) { 
                matriz[linha][coluna] = 0; 
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Matriz modificada: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoLinhas; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tamanhoColunas; j++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```